# Como fazer controle de versão para arquivo JS, CSS, HTML e etc

Tags: javascript, grunt

Gostaria de saber como fazer o controle de versionamento dos meus arquivos Js, CSS e HTML, pois quando subo uma nova versão no servidor, o website fica com cache dos arquivos.

Vi que existe a `grunt-usemin`, mas não encontrei nenhuma explicação de como usá-lo.

Gostaria de deixar os arquivos desse jeito:

```
meuscript.js?v=0123456
```

Comment: apagou a cache do navegador antes de tentar?

Comment: PHP ou asp.net ou outra coisa?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. quero fazer em asp.net mesmo

Comment: @ihavenokia sim, mas gostaria de implementar uma solução nesse tipo

Answer (score 1):

### asp.net-mvc

Em asp.net-mvc pode experimentar a solução [**desta resposta do SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316991/1518921)

```
public static class JavascriptExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString IncludeVersionedJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
    {
        string version = GetVersion(helper, filename);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + filename + version + "'></script>");
    }

    private static string GetVersion(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
    {
        var context = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;

        if (context.Cache[filename] == null)
        {
            var physicalPath = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
            var version = $"?v={new System.IO.FileInfo(physicalPath).LastWriteTime.ToString("MMddHHmmss")}";
            context.Cache.Add(filename, version, null,
              DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero,
              CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            return version;
        }
        else
        {
            return context.Cache[filename] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

E no View chame assim:

```
@Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/meuscriptminificado.js")
```

Que vai resultar nisto:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/meuscriptminificado.js?20111129120000'></script>
```

---

### ASP.NET Core MVC

No asp.net core (asp.net-mvc 6) existe o `asp-append-version` e pode usar assim:

```
<script src="scripts/meujs.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<link href="styles/meucss.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
```

---

### PHP

Com PHP pode usar `filemtime`, algo que seria como:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/meucss.css?v=<?php echo filemtime('caminho/real/styles/meucss.css'); ?>">

<script src="scripts/meujs.js?v=<?php echo filemtime('caminho/real/scripts/meujs.js'); ?>"></script>
```

No entanto crie uma função que pode facilitar bastante e no caso bastaria chamar `IncludeVersioned`, assim:

```
<?php
function IncludeVersioned($file) {
     $absoluto = 'ect/var/www/caminho/dos/resources/'; # ajuste aqui
     if (is_file($absoluto . $file)) {
          $time = $absoluto . $file;

          $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

          switch ($ext) {
               case 'js':
                   echo '<script src="', $file,'?v=', $time,'"></script>';
               break;
               case 'css':
                   echo '<link href="', $file,'?v=', $time,'" rel="stylesheet">;
               break;
               default:
                   echo '<!-- tipo invalido de resource -->';
          }
     } else {
           echo '<!-- resource não encontrado -->';
     }
}
?>

<?php IncludeVersioned('scripts/foo.js'); ?>
<?php IncludeVersioned('styles/foo.css'); ?>
```

Comment: no meu caso, minha aplicação é web api, então não consigo referenciar o script neste modo @Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/meuscriptminificado.js"). Tem algum outro modo de chamar esse método?

Comment: @T.Morciani WebApi é para usar com aplicações Rest, para sites "normais" use o MVC. Nota: é possivel usar WebAPI e MVC no mesmo projeto.

Comment: ah sim, entendi.Mas tem como eu utilizar essa solução referenciando os scripts neste modo:  <script src=""></script> ?

Comment: @T.Morciani sim, o método `@Html.IncludeVersionedJs` vai gerar o `<script src=""></script>` sozinho pra ti. Esta usando asp.net-mvc 4, 5 ou 6?

Comment: estou usando web api purao, nao tem nada de mvc. Estou usando uma index para referenciar todos os meus scripts e dai não consigo utilizar "@Html".

Comment: @T.Morciani mas webapi é pra criar API do tipo Rest, acho que você esta usando algo da maneira mais improdutiva e não padronizada, o que dificulta responder em muito, pois provavelmente você inventou uma lógica propria quebrando o sentido do webapi.